# FFMPEG: [h264 @ 0x557355e68f80] co located POCs unavailable and mmco: unref short failure for sending frames over ffmpeg piped subprocess

Tags: ffmpeg, video

Getting unref short failure and co located POCs unavailable

[image: Getting unref short failure and co located POCs unavailable]

```
command = ['ffmpeg',
               '-y',
               '-f', 'rawvideo',
               '-vcodec', 'rawvideo',
               '-pix_fmt', 'bgr24',
               '-s', "{}x{}".format(width, height),
               # '-framerate', '5',
               '-r', str(fps),
               '-i', '-',
               '-c:v', 'libx264',
               '-pix_fmt', 'yuv420p',
               '-preset', 'ultrafast',
               '-f', 'flv',
               '-flvflags', 'no_duration_filesize',
               rtmp_live_url]

piped_process = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
piped_process_new.stdin.write(frame.tostring())
```

Using above command to send frames from opencv to a specific rtmp url.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.